# jquery check if class is assigned or not

Tags: jquery, class, accordion

I have a problem with my attempt to create an accordion like menu.

The thing is everything works great. First "balloon" opens up and slides, correct class is added to active balloon, but the problem is when you click on an image holder on a balloon that already has the "active" class added. JQuery seems to add this style:

`display: block; overflow: hidden;`

and it messes up my CSS.

So my question is how to check to see if the user already clicked on an "active balloon" and if that is the case,  do NOTHING (or slide it back so it's closed) OR how to remove that additional style that is added - and why is it added in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

you can check the existance of class as

```
if($("element").hasClass("class"))
```

[**hasClass**](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery sliding animation adds those styles when its shows the content.

You can use `hasClass` to check if the `active` class is present on the element or not.

```js
if(!$(element).hasClass('active')){
    //Do something
}
```

If you want to toggle the sliding behavior you can use the `slideToggle` method.

```js
$(element).slideToggle(500, function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   if($this.is(':visible')){
       $this.addClass('active');
   }
   else{
       $this.removeClass('active');
   }
});
```

The `slideToggle` method takes a second parameter as a callback which is executed at the end of animation. You can use that and add/remove the required class conditionally.

Note that I am using the `is()` method to check if the element is visible or not using the pseudo selector `:visible`.

For more information check the API reference of the following methods

- [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)
- [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)
- [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Comment: Hi, I've wrapped my function into `if (!$(#accordion li).hasClass('active')) { function here....` but it now won't do the sliding at all ?

Comment: `hasClass('active')` will return `true` if the element has `active` class. Are you sure you want to check for that condition?

Comment: well actually yes, and if it has class active - I would like to do absolutely "nothing". Right now it adds a piece of inline CSS to already active element and I really don't need to do anything with already active li. Thanks !

Comment: There is my code here: `http://testing.tribehosting.com/` when I added `if (!$(#accordion li).hasClass('active'))` it won't expand anything ?